# How to test propagating screen like splash screen?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

When i open my app it shows splash screen for 3 sec and automatically goes to welcome screen. As appium need certain time to load, while running my app from appium i am unable to test the splash screen. It automatically goes to welcome screen before i can test splash screen. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you tried restarting​ splash screen using driver.startActivity(). As per my understanding splash screen main aim is to just act as an app launchable screen... You can also take screenshot of the screen and compare using sikuli...

Comment: I have checked it by increasing the splash screen time from Android Studio and build the apk, you can use the way if you have access the code.